# How to open the view with the keyboard appearing when the view is already loaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a requirement where I have a textfield in a view. When I want to open the view by switching the tab (TabBased Application), first time when the view is loaded the keyboard appears because i loadview method is called. But when I switch to tab2 and again switch to tab1 again, load view is not called. I want the keyboard to appear every time I open the tab1 page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `-viewWillAppear:` in your view controller to send your text field a `-becomeFirstResponder` message, e.g.:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: I have done the same thing... But ViewWillAppear method is not called everytime......
Here is the Code

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 [searchForProduct becomeFirstResponder];
}

Please Help

Comment: You code should work, assuming all the objects are instantiated and wired up. Try adding an `NSLog` statement to verify that `-viewWillAppear:` gets called. Also make sure `searchForProduct` isn't `nil` and/or that it is hooked up properly if you're using Interface Builder for your view.

Comment: searchForProduct is not released.. It contains the memory allocation... The Problem is viewWillAppear Method is never called...

Comment: What class are you putting `-viewWillAppear:` into? Are you putting it into a `UIViewController` subclass or a `UIView` subclass or some other subclass?

Comment: I am putting it in the UIViewController Class

Comment: If you're putting it into a view controller, then it should get called. Put an `NSLog` statement in the `-viewWillAppear:` method and watch the Console. If you're not getting a log statement printed to the Console, then something else is wrong with your application unrelated to this.

Comment: User `viewDidAppear`, rather than `viewWillAppear`. "Make sure that your app has established its object graph before assigning an object to be the first responder. For example, you typically call the becomeFirstResponder method in an override of the viewDidAppear: method. If you try to assign the first responder in viewWillAppear:, your object graph is not yet established, so the becomeFirstResponder method returns NO. -https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html