# How to display the keyboard automatically when a view appears

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard, viewwillappear

How can I make the keyboard appearing when a view is displayed?

Comment: Try This **textfield.becomeFirstResponder()**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force keyboard to show up via button (iPhone sdk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750445/force-keyboard-to-show-up-via-button-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Hello, I've already tried this, but I want the keyboard automatically appears without tapping on the textfield.

Comment: @Blisko Yes, you can add that line on viewDidLoad(), than it will appear automatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open the view with the keyboard appearing when the view is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651136/how-to-open-the-view-with-the-keyboard-appearing-when-the-view-is-loaded)

Answer (score 6):

Try this code in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear

```
textfieldname.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update for SwiftUI 3**

If you are using UIViewRepresentable, you can use `.becomeFirstResponder()` there.

Answer (score -2):

Put below code in `ViewDidLoad`

```
textfieldname.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: Well, to strictly answer the question, it would be done on `viewWillAppear` instead.

Comment: Yes, you can put my code on viewillappear() instead of viewdid load

Comment: I've put it in the ViewDidLoad but the keyboard didn't appear automatically. 
I don't use a textfied, but a custom view. Is this linked?

Comment: This code only work with the controls that allow editing of text or texting,like UITextField and UITextView

Comment: @Blisko Can you tell us a little more about the custom view? Does it contain a text field that you are trying to type into? If so, you might want to do something such as `customView.textField.becomeFirstResponder()`

Comment: Hi I ve managed to display the keyboard with becomeFirstResponder() in the custom view.